# How does adjectival nominalisation work in Russian?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные

> отрицать **очевидное** =  *deny **the obvious***

In German, for instance, an adjective can perform the function of a noun by taking the form of:

> definitite article + adjective in neutral gender (with a capitalised first letter)

How does it generally work in Russian? Is it enough to use the neutral singular form of an adjective without capitalising its first letter or adding some particle?

Comment: I'll just give you a nice and undue forgotten example: `ночное`. [Look](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5) [here](http://www.ljpoisk.ru/archive/10864058.html).

Comment: Related https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14130/why-is-the-adjective-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-in-neuter-gender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern Russian, you just put the adjective in full neuter singular, as in your example. No capitalization or anything needed:

> - Никто не обнимет необъятного
> - Мы за всё хорошее, против всего плохого
> - Былое и думы

In Church Slavonic and Old Russian, you had to put the adjective in neuter plural. Russian has a number of words like *преисподняя; святая святых; прочая, прочая, прочая* etc. which are formed according to this paradigm, but it is not productive anymore.

Comment: just to clarify for myself, `вселенная, преисподняя, святая святых` are in neuter **plural** of Church-Slavonic, right?

Comment: "Вселенная" derives from "въселенаѩ" which is a calque of old greek "_oikoumene_" (οἰκουμένη) which is a passive adverb. So it's not a neuter plural.

Comment: passive adverb? not adjective or participle? what are other examples of passive adverbs in Russian? i can think of `приглушённо` (from `приглушить -> приглушённый`) but strictly speaking it's not passive, it's just an adverb, isn't it?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Participle, I meant participle! Not adverb.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка yes, neuter plural. *восплачутся вся колѣна земная* means "all the tribes of the earth will mourn", *колѣно* being neuter.

Comment: @Abakan: you're right, *вселенная* might be the odd one out here.